# como retorna um array de uma função

Tags: php, mysql, array, funções

Quero pegar os dados de um array de um SELECT

```
public function aluno($cod)
{
    $cod = "";
    global $pdo;
    $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT 
    KS0042.CODALUNO, ks0300.ALUNO 
    From KS0042
    Inner Join KS0300 ON KS0300.CODALUNO = KS0042.CODALUNO And KS0300.CODENTIDADE = 
    KS0042.CODENTIDADE 
    Inner Join KS0100 ON KS0100.CODCADASTRO = KS0042.CODCADASTRO And KS0100.CODENTIDADE = 
    KS0042.CODENTIDADE
    Where KS0042.CODCADASTRO = :c");
    $sql->bindValue(":c",$cod);
    $sql->execute();
    $dado = $sql->fetchAll();
    return $dado;
    }
```

Quero usar o dado nesse bloco de código, porém não consigo retorna o array $dado:

```
   $u->conectar("KSSOFTNOVO","localhost","root","");

  if ($msgErro == "") {
     $u->aluno($cod);
  }
 }
  ?>

   <div class="center"> 

    <h5 id="aluno">Selecione o aluno:</h5>
    <form method="post">

    <select name="nome" id="nome">
    <?php 
      if (count($dado)) {
        foreach ($dado as $dados) {

          
       
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $dados['CODALUNO']?>"><?php echo $dados['ALUNO'] ?></option>
    <?php
        }
      }

      
     
      ?>
   </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dentro da função `aluno($cod)` você está setando a variável `$cod` para uma valor vazio:

```
public function aluno($cod)
{
    $cod = "";
...
```

Provavelmente este é o motivo que não está retornando nada, pois não está encontrando nenhum aluno com código = `""`.
Tente remover esta linha da função.